# Combining Appended Values in PHP Function Output

Tags: php, user-defined-functions

I have the following PHP function which "renders" an output from appended values:

```
protected function getFieldRow($label, $value, $encode = true)
{
    if (empty($value))
    {
        return '';
    }       
    return FoxHtmlElem::create()->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('div')->classes('field-title')->text(JFilterInput::getInstance()->clean($label .= ":&nbsp;")))->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('div')->classes('field-content')->html($encode ? nl2br(FoxHtmlEncoder::encode(JFilterInput::getInstance()->clean($value))) : $value))->render();
}
```

Which outputs to a list like this:

```
<div class="field-title">Label : </div><div class="field-content">Value</div>
<div class="field-title">Label : </div><div class="field-content">Value</div>
<div class="field-title">Label : </div><div class="field-content">Value</div>
```

How can I change the function so that it combines the two appended values inside the same div like this:

```
<div class="field-content">Label : Value</div>
<div class="field-content">Label : Value</div>
<div class="field-content">Label : Value</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to do this:

```
<?php

return FoxHtmlElem::create()
->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('div')
->classes('field-content')
->html( JFilterInput::getInstance()->clean($label .= ":&nbsp;"). ($encode ? nl2br(FoxHtmlEncoder::encode(JFilterInput::getInstance()->clean($value))) : $value)))->render();
```

Just move the label variable into the HTML method instead of creating a separate div.

Comment: I wonder why someone first down voted the question. Always willing to learn.. anyway, simply moving the label variable works beautifully. Huge thanks for the clear explanation, have a great day.